# Interface hierarchy design for separate domains

Tags: php, object-oriented, interfaces, type-systems

There are businesses and people. People could be liked and businesses could be commented on:

```
class Like
class Comment

class Person implements iLikeTarget
class Business implements iCommentTarget
```

Likes and comments are performed by a user(person) so they are authored:

```
class Like implements iAuthored
class Comment implements iAuthored
```

People's like could also be used in their history:

```
class history
class Like implements iAuthored, iHistoryTarget
```

Now, a smart developer comes and says each history is attached to a user so history should be authored:

```
interface iHistoryTarget extends iAuthored
```

so it could be removed from `class Like`:

```
class Person implements iLikeTarget
class Business implements iCommentTarget

class Like implements iHistoryTarget
class Comment implements iAuthored

class history

interface iHistoryTarget extends iAuthored
```

Here, another smart guy comes with a question: How could I capture the `Authored` fact in `Like` and `Comment` classes? He may knows nothing about `history` concept in the project.

By scalling these kind of functionallities, interfaces may goes to their encapsulated types which cause more type strength, on the other hand explicitness suffered and also code end users will face much pain to process.
So here is the question:
Should I encapsulate those dependant types to their parent types (interface hierarchies) or not or explicitly repeat each type for every single level of my type system or ...?

Comment: Do you know traits, refinements, subject-oriented programming, context oriented programming, data-context-interaction? Maybe they can help here.

Comment: yeah. How could they help me?

Answer (score 1):

I would say being an authored object is independent of being a history item so the way to reflect the domain more closely would be:

`class Like implements iHistoryItem, iAuthored`

This says that even if `Like` was *not* a history item, it would still be an authored action.